# How to validate form fields without model name in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

How can I validate form data without model name. When I print `$this->data` I get the data in following array format. But fields doesn't contain model name.

```
Array
 (
  [select_family] => Select
  [select_cores] => Select
  [select_color] => Select
  [select_back_color] => Select
  [select_panel] => Select
  [select_design] => Select
  [select_thickness] => Select
  [select_edge] => Select
  [quantity] => 
  [save] => Save

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the form submitted fields won't contain the model name, you have to specify the appropriate model and then write validation rules for your field

Comment: can't you just associate those inputs to some model?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Model name becasue validation didn't know where and what validate.

Ofcourse You can set Model name before validation (e.g. `beforeValidation` callback or before `$this->Model->set()` in controller)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from UI then you just need to do this in your controller's action

```
(
[select_family] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_cores] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_color] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_back_color] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_panel] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_design] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_thickness] => $this->request->data['x'],
[select_edge] => $this->request->data['x'],
[quantity] => 
[save] => Save

)
```

where `x` is your UI input field name.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and validate these data structures:

Default:

```
Array
(
    [ModelName] => Array
    (
        [fieldname1] => 'value'
        [fieldname2] => 'value'
    )
)
```

Saving multiple records:

```
$data = array(
    array('title' => 'title 1'),
    array('title' => 'title 2')
);
```

So convert your data array for an appropriate format before validating/saving it. For example:

```
$data['ModelName'] = $this->data;
$this->save($data);
```

or

```
$data = array($this->data);
$this->saveMany($data);
```